# Need help iterating through Python dict keys/values and INSERTing into SQL DB

Tags: python, sql, azure, pyodbc

I made a call to request data from Weight Gurus, which returns in the format of a python dictionary with keys and values of course.  I need to take the data retrieved from this call and INSERT each key/value pair as an individual row.

So far I have managed to get the data from Weight Gurus and also establish a connection to my DB within python, but no luck with iterating through the dict to INSERT each value pair into an individual row.

```
# Login and get the auth token
data = {"email": "", "password": ""}
login_response = requests.post("https://api.weightgurus.com/v3/account/login", data=data)
login_json = login_response.json()

# grab all your data
data_response = requests.get(
    "https://api.weightgurus.com/v3/operation/",
    headers={
        "Authorization": f'Bearer {login_json["accessToken"]}',
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    },
)

scale_data_json = data_response.json()
for entry in scale_data_json["operations"]:
    print(entry)


import pyodbc    
server = ''
database = ''
username = ''
password = ''
driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

The dictionary in question is comprised of 9 keys.  Each key is a column within my table called BodyComposition.  Each key value pair should be an individual row.  My table also has an increment ID field for the primary key if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not exactly sure what I am doing here, but this is the code I am trying to write to make this work: for entry in scale_data_json["operations"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO BodyComposition (BMI, BodyFat, Entrytimestamp, MuscleMass, OperationType, ServerTimestamp, Source, Water, Weight) VALUES (j, j, j, j, j, j, j, j, j)")

Comment: The following code successfully loops through all 404 rows and inserts the data into my table, except of course it is not correct as I need to be selecting each row: for entry in scale_data_json["operations"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO BodyComposition (BMI, BodyFat, Entrytimestamp, MuscleMass, OperationType, ServerTimestamp, Source, Water, Weight) VALUES (10, 10, '2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 50, 'create', '2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 'bluetooth scale', 37, 21)") 
cnxn.commit()

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the data shape, but if scale_data_json["operations"] is a dict, you are looping through its keys in the for loop, not the entries. You can use scale_data_json["operations"].items() to iterate through the (key, value) pairs of the dict. Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: @DylanJanszen Please *edit your question* with additional detail. Don't include it in comments, as unformatted code is very difficult to read and understand. Also, you haven't shown what the data looks like, as returned from the original API call. Please edit to include that as well (and properly formatted for readability).

Comment: I am now trying to use Pandas to solve the problem, but now I can not get pyodbc and pandas to play nicely.  Keep getting database driver errors.  Here is what the data look like in pandas though... https://imgur.com/a/ohmN5HA Basically just need this to_sql, but can't seem to get it

Comment: You shouldn't need Pandas for this, have you tried vekerdyb's solution, and if so what was the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider unpacking your collection of dictionaries into key/value tuples and then parameterize the values tuple in the loop. Assuming the below data structure (list of dictionaries):

```
scale_data_json["operations"] = [{'BMI': 0, 'BodyFat': 10, 
                                  'Entrytimestamp': '2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 
                                  'MuscleMass': 50, 'OperationType': 'create',
                                  'ServerTimestamp':'2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 
                                  'Source':'bluetooth scale', 
                                  'Water':37, 'Weight':21},
                                 {'BMI': 0, 'BodyFat': 10, 
                                  'Entrytimestamp': '2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 
                                  'MuscleMass': 50, 'OperationType': 'create',
                                  'ServerTimestamp':'2018-01-21T19:37:47.821Z', 
                                  'Source':'bluetooth scale', 
                                  'Water':37, 'Weight':21},
                                ...]
```

Loop through each dictionary, unpack the values with `zip` and then bind them in `cursor.execute`:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = """INSERT INTO BodyComposition (BMI, BodyFat, Entrytimestamp, 
                                      MuscleMass, OperationType, ServerTimestamp, 
                                      Source, Water, Weight) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      """

# LOOP, UNPACK, BIND PARAMS
for entry in scale_data_json["operations"]:
    keys, values = zip(*entry.items())
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: I receive this error message "DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'create' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")".  I am not sure why it is trying to convert to an int? In my database it is a char(6)

Comment: Fixed it thanks to you.  My SQL variable/object had to be reorganized!